# QGIS - overlay_within on WFS Layer joined with CSV Table possible?

Tags: qgis, wfs

I am trying to display three attributes of different layers containing geometries and data of districts and parcels. This I am trying to achieve by ruled-based labeling in one layer, in order to have them stuck together.

[image: this is what it is supposed to look like]

In a different state with different data, instead of names only INSPIRE-Numbers are provided, so I had to join the attributes with a prepared *.csv table with the fitting names to have them displayed. But as it seems, joined attributes can not be displayed when using the command overly_within?

This is an example code for layers that have no joined attributes...

```sql
'Gemarkung '  || 
array_first(
    overlay_within(
        layer:='Gemarkungen_MV',
        expression:=gmkname
    )
)  ||  '\n'  || "flurname"
```

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example of the code and joined dataset (screenshot of csv for example), where you haven't been able to use `overlay_within()`?

Comment: Not really sure what exactly you have and what the problem is. You should provide a samplöe project with sample data for testing. Otherwise its difficult to help.